# Toggling Highlights In JTextArea

Tags: swing, jtextarea

I have a JTextArea where lines are highlighted upon right-click. While I could achieve this ([using some great help from my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053056/highlight-text-in-jtextarea-in-presence-of-duplicate-lines)), however I would also want some kind of a toggle functionality i.e. if a line is not highlighted, right-click would highlight it and vice-versa.

**With reference to this, is it possible to check whether the selected line is already highlighted or not?** Comments/Suggestions?

I understand one way of doing this is to keep a track of all the highlights (maybe using a HashMap [as shown in the example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306901/how-to-change-highlighting-color-in-java-swing-textarea-and-also-change-the-be/10309277#10309277)) but this would slightly add to the complexity because I'm writing this method in a helper class that serves to multiple tabs containing these text areas. Any other alternative solution would be very helpful (*as in toggling the highlights*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have your answer right [there in the link you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10309277/613495).

Just write your own class extending the `JTextArea` where each instance will be responsible for storing its highlights then use your own class instead.

*BTW @nIcE cOw great answer (+1 there).*

Answer (score 2):

`SWT` has a `StyledText` class.

You could write a styled text class for Swing, implementing the `Document` interface, that keeps track of the highlights and whatever other text decorations you want to keep track of.  This class would encapsulate the methods that determine the decorations at a given character position in the styled text.