# move up down button in the text areas

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextarea, jtextcomponent

I have two text areas on the screen, I have made bold the different words between two text areas and I want to have a button for up and down to go the different words on the text areas. Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes but I suggest you to be a little more precise. Post some code showing what you have tried since now. Your question is still to much vague to get an answer here.

Comment: There are many related Q&As [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1559593/vstl) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1573438/jes) that may help you clarify your question.

Comment: yes you are right but I don't know any idea how i can do it, I'm still researching now, can you tell me some kind of method for that. I have found setDefaultButton now but I'm not sure that is not my solution of my problem. @Heisenbug  heisenberg ehehe comes up heisenberg from breaking bad sorry im kidding :)

Comment: Seems to me what you need is `modelToView()` and `viewToModel()`, which is inherited by `JTextArea`  from `JTextComponent`. Here is one [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10309277/1057230) and another [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10463120/1057230), that might can help you

Answer (score 3):

- have to look at [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html), but notice isn't designated for nice formatting or higlighting, then to use [JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) instead
- [TextUtilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Utilities.html) can help you to find out desired indexes rellative to screen or rellative to the model ([Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/class-use/Document.html))

Comment: can I use keyEvent for that up or down?

Comment: @zenx : `KeyEvent` are not a good option when it comes to Swing. ***[KeyBinding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)*** is what goes with Swing.