# highlight some words in the jeditorpane in java swing

Tags: java, swing, awt, jeditorpane, swing-highlighter

I am working on a swing application in which i have to show **HTML** files in `JEditorPane`. I have to highlight some text e.g. For all  occurrences of **boy** . I am using the following code 
but it is highlighting the whole text of `JEditorPane` :

```
try
{          
    javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter highlightPainter = 
        new javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.YELLOW);
    textPane.getHighlighter().addHighlight(startPos, endPos, 
    highlightPainter);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

but its highlighting the entire document . In this method what is the role of 
`startPos`   and `endPos` ?

Comment: Please have a look at this wonderful [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9651404/1057230) by @mKorbel and this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10309277/1057230), might be these will help. Moreover, you talking about `Swing` and not `awt` here, so better would be to add the tag for **Swing** too.

Comment: FWIW: Writing `catch(Exception ex){}` is making sure to give yourself a bad headache one day... Never write an empty "catch exception" block. Always leave a trace (a log, a message to the console...)

Comment: Also [Highlight a word in jeditorpane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448558/highlight-a-word-in-jeditorpane/13448656#13448656)

Answer (score 0):

you have to define the keywords first which means you need to iterate the whole content, when the words equal keyword, addHighLight it. You don't except the JeditorPane recoginise the keyword for you.

Comment: @driodev This *is* an answer to the question. It's not requesting clarification at all.

Comment: @Servy go to that review link and see. Its not only my comment

Comment: @driodev So because other people also chose the wrong action from review it's okay?  That's not how that works.  If I could reply to them as well, I would.