# highlight multiple words in java

Tags: java, applet

I am very new to Java. I want to write a program which simulates a garden. It must have 3 buttons being centre, side and anywhere. When i press centre it should highlight names of plants which are to be planted to the centre of the garden, when i press side, it highlights names to be planted on the sides

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Please show what you've tried already -- a code sample will increase your chances of getting meaningful assistance.

Comment: public class Centre implements ActionListener {

  private JTextPane1 comp;

  private String textToHighlight;

  public MultiHighlight(jTextPane1 c, String chars) {
    comp = c;
    charsToHighlight = chars;
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
Highlighter h = comp.getHighlighter();
    h.removeAllHighlights();
    String text = jTextPane1.getText();
    String words[] = text.split(" ");
for(int i = 0;i<words.length;i++){
    String temp = words[i];

Comment: if(temp.equals("word")){
        try{
        h.addHighlight(i, temp.length(), DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
}
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Gadernplanner");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    area

Comment: .setText("Hydrangea Roses Lawn Acca Alkanna Fragaria Cyclamen ");
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(area), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JButton b = new JButton("Central");
    b.addActionListener(new MultiHighlight(area, "Roses"));
    frame.getContentPane().add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

Comment: @Abrar I cannot make this work, find above my code

Comment: You can find your answer [here][1].

Please ck it.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086165/jtextpane-highlight-multiple-words

Comment: You can find your answer [here][1].

Please ck it.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086165/jtextpane-highlight-multiple-words

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Highlighter h = jTextPane1.getHighlighter();
    h.removeAllHighlights();
    String text = jTextPane1.getText();
    String words[] = text.split(" ");
for(int i = 0;i<words.length;i++){
    String temp = words[i];
    if(temp.equals("word")){
        try{
        h.addHighlight(i, temp.length(), DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```